# Unable to include Arial font in FOPTransformer

Tags: java, alfresco, truetype, apache-fop

I am working on an application which has some forms and then using FOP it creates pdf files. PDF files that are getting generated are in Time New Roman but I want them in Arial font. I added arial.ttf in projectName->fonts->arial.ttf as described [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150525132108/http://www.publicstaticfinal.de/2011/01/26/fop-embedding-fonts-from-classpath/).

This ttf and code has to go into alfresco amp file but right now I havent added it as jar file for arial.ttf because I am not sure how to make a jar file with just .ttf file, Here is what I did to accomplish this but pdf are still in times new roman:
 fopconfig:

```
<fop version="0.94">
 <base>./</base>
 <font-base>./</font-base>
 <renderer mime="application/postscript">
 <fonts>
        <font kerning="yes" embed-url="/fonts/arial.ttf" encoding-mode="auto">
            <font-triplet name="Arial" style="normal" weight="normal" />
        </font>
    </fonts>
   </renderer>
</fop>
```

Created a class file as follows:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.URIResolver;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class ClasspathUriResolver implements URIResolver
{

  public Source resolve(String href, String base) throws TransformerException
  {
    Source source = null;
    InputStream inputStream = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(href);
    if (inputStream != null)
    {
      source = new StreamSource(inputStream);
    }
    return source;
  }
}
```

And here is part of my code for FOPTranformer:

```
   FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();
     FOURIResolver uriResolver = (FOURIResolver)fopFactory.getURIResolver();
     uriResolver.setCustomURIResolver(new ClasspathUriResolver());
     FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to load the font-configuration when you create the FopFactory, see http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.0/embedding.html#config-external

However FOP will use the Arial font by default if you specify "sans-serf" as font-family in the XSL-FO file.

Comment: Thank you a lot, it saved my time a lot :)